# YouTube OAuth 2.0 - GET Request getting NULL from var_dump();

Tags: php, json, oauth-2.0, youtube-api

I've been working with YouTube OAuth 2.0 and i'm having some problems. I've been using the example and I've got up to the stage where the Google channel is being authenticated and redirecting back with a code.

When trying to send a GET request to grab some channel data from the OAuth scopes i'm getting a "NULL" response and i'm unsure why.

(Validate contains a working request)

```
echo "<a href='$validate'>Login with Google for advanced analytics</a>";


$channel_data = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DMINE&start-date=2014-08-01&end-date=2014-09-01&metrics=views&key={api_key}');
$channel_data = json_decode($channel_data, true);

echo "<br />";
var_dump($channel_data);
```

It seems to work in the example request found https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/

Comment: I've never worked with the analytics api, but when working with the data api, you need to send the access token (the code you wrote about) within the query string (like `http://[...]/?[your arguments]&access_token=[your access token]`)

Comment: That's in the non-shown code, that's what $validate is.

Comment: No, `$validate` has to be an URL. What I mean is that OAuth returns a code which you have to exchange for an access_token. This access token has to be in the url of the api request. (Unlike I wrote above, the code you referred to is not the access token)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a misunderstanding of [how to implement OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/authentication?hl=de#server-side-apps).

This step-by-step instruction is a summary of the site I've linked:

1. create a client id for web application in the developer console
2. make your user go to the auth url
3. when he/she completed the process, the user will be redirected to the redirect uri you specified.
4. on this page, your php script has to grab the `code`-query (`$_GET['code']`)
5. next, you have to make a request (containing the code) to a page which provides you with an access token and a refresh token. An access token expires after 1h, then you have to get a new one with your refresh token
6. once you have the access token, you can start making api requests

On the website linked at the top, you'll find detailed instructions.
Hope this helps :)

**UPDATE**

In order to exchange the code for the tokens, you have to perform a post request. I don't think that'l work with `file_get_contents`. I recommend using [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) here.

This code should work for you, but it's not tested:

```
$url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';

$postfields = [
    'code'=>'YOUR_CODE',
    'client_id'=>'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
    'client_secret'=>'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
    'redirect_uri'=>'YOUR_REDIRECT_URI',
    'grant_type'=>'authorization_code'
];


$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, count($postfields));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postfields));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($response);
```

`$response` now is an associative array with the keys `access_token, token_type, expires_in, refresh_token`. `token_type` is always `Bearer` and `expires_in` is always `3600`. The other two are the important ones and you should store them safely!

You can find your client id and client secret in the developer console.

But please note that in this example, the ssl verification is disabled. That means your connection is not safe.

Comment: Amazing Answer. It's my fault i can't follow instructions! Just before i start a new question about 5). I'm not too sure how i would go about sending a request with the code. I didn't understand it.

Comment: Please have a look on the update I made, should make it more clear.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this using php? I'm getting an error from the array $postfield = "[" even though my PHP version is 5.6

Comment: What do you mean? This is PHP! Try to just copy & paste this to a blank page and add `var_dump($response);` to the code. When you view the page, you should get an `invalid_request`-error (because of the placeholders). If this happens, the request works fine. Now replace the placeholders with your values and you will get the tokens.

Comment: When i say with PHP, i meant without cURL, sorry i didn't make myself clear enough. Even with the placeholders correctly filled in i get a parse error.

Comment: cURL is probably disabled in your php.ini. Search for a line like `;extension=php_curl.dll`. If there is one, delete the leading semicolon, otherwise add it (without the semicolon).

Comment: No it isn't. I don't like using cURL.

Comment: Ok, then I can't help you.

Comment: Hai @paolo i have copy pasted your code and it doesn't seems to work, i am sure that my CURL from my local environment is working. please suggest me a solution

Comment: I think its obvious that you can't just copy & paste it because of the placeholders. Are you sure you filled in valid values? Do you get any errors?